# left outer join - sort operations in the query plan - any ways of tuning this simple query?

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, execution-plan, sort-operator, query-performance

while working on the query below in order to answer this question:

[How to query chart data in a database agnostic way?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164634/how-to-query-chart-data-in-a-database-agnostic-way/164907#164907)

Having the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#foo] ( 
[creation]  DATETIME                         NOT NULL,
[value]     MONEY                                NULL,
[DT]        AS (CONVERT([date],[CREATION])) PERSISTED)


-- add a clustered index on the dt column
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_FOO ON #FOO(DT)
GO
```

and this other table for joining:

```
create table #bar (dt date primary key clustered)
go
```

[the loading of data into these tables can be found here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164634/how-to-query-chart-data-in-a-database-agnostic-way/164907#164907).

But when running the following query:

```
WITH RADHE AS (
SELECT THE_ROW=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.DT ORDER BY B.DT),
       THE_DATE=B.dt,
       THE_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS_ON_THIS_DAY=CASE WHEN F.DT IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY F.DT ) END ,
       THE_TOTAL_VALUE_FOR_THE_DAY=COALESCE(SUM(F.VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY b.DT ),0)

FROM #BAR B
LEFT OUTER JOIN #FOO F
ON B.dt = F.dt
)

--get rid of the duplicates and present the result
SELECT 
THE_DATE,
THE_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS_ON_THIS_DAY,
THE_TOTAL_VALUE_FOR_THE_DAY
FROM RADHE
WHERE THE_ROW = 1
```

I get something like this picture below, which is exactly what I was looking for.

[image]

But the execution plan generated has several Sort and Nested Loops Operations, as you can see on the picture below.

[The full query plan can be found here.](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1NG6sOFe)

[image]

this is a very simple operation, a left outer join between 2 tables, the indexes are already ordered, and therefore I was wondering if I could simplify the query plan.

alternatively, I could change the query code.

why exactly do we need `nested loops` 2 times and `sort` 2 times in the query plan?

Comment: At least one of the sorts is explicitly requested by using `ORDER BY` in the second line of your CTE. This is not as simple as you think, because you're using ranking queries, which need to order the data in the manner you require.

Comment: Not sure it matters, but have you noticed that you're partitioning both by `B.DT` and `F.DT`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an index that provides ordering by `B.DT` but

- the plan first evaluates `THE_ROW` using this order
- then the right hand sort orders by `F.DT` to evaluate `THE_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS_ON_THIS_DAY`
- and finally the left hand sort puts things back into `B.DT` order for the `THE_TOTAL_VALUE_FOR_THE_DAY`.

You can get rid of one of the sorts by simply changing the order of the columns in the CTE so the `F.DT` one appears last ([The connect item for this Unnecessary Sort is here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/679342/unnecessary-sort))

```
WITH RADHE AS (
SELECT THE_ROW=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.DT ORDER BY B.DT),
       THE_DATE=B.dt ,
       THE_TOTAL_VALUE_FOR_THE_DAY=COALESCE(SUM(F.VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY b.DT ),0),
       THE_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS_ON_THIS_DAY=CASE WHEN F.DT IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY F.DT ) END

FROM #BAR B
LEFT OUTER JOIN #FOO F
ON B.dt = F.dt
)
```

But you can get rid of both by changing the definition of `THE_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS_ON_THIS_DAY` to

```
CASE WHEN F.DT IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY B.DT ) END
```

So it uses the same partitioning definition as the rest of the functions.

This shouldn't change anything in your example as your `CASE` expression will just assign `0` to any non matched rows anyway.

As for the rest of the plan see [Partitioning and the Common Subexpression Spool](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/partitioning-and-the-common-subexpression-spool.aspx)

(Plan afterwards with no sorts)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you are making this a lot harder than it needs to be

```
SELECT THE_DATE = B.dt,
       THE_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS_ON_THIS_DAY = COUNT(F.DT),
       THE_TOTAL_VALUE_FOR_THE_DAY = SUM(ISNULL(F.VALUE, 0))
FROM   #BAR B
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #FOO F
         ON B.dt = F.dt
GROUP  BY B.dt
```